# Apply hover effect to child div only, without affecting parents with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this case where I'm using nested blocks with same class (project is in Angular, with nested components from same type). Is there any way to apply hover state only to certain div, without affecting parent div with same class?

In below example you can see that when you hover on a child div, also it's parent div gets red background.

```css
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.block:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block">
        </div>
        <div class="block">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is eligible to you just highlight only child elements, then we  can apply more stricted rule:

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.block > .block:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block">
      </div>
      <div class="block">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```